# fork() to search through a 3D array C programming

Tags: c, multidimensional-array, fork

I just learned about fork on the web, I understand the main principle with the child and parent processes but I am still a little bit confused on how we can use fork to search faster through a 3D array. Can anyone give a quick coded example to show how it works ?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Fork can make things run faster by allowing the calculations to be split up amongst the processors. Here's example code using a flat array (it's easier to get the concept across with a flat array instead of 3d array):

```
int main() {
    int i;
    int array[] = {0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10};
    int findThisNumber = 8;
    int pid = fork(); //split into two processes
                      //the parent return the childs pid
                      //and the child returns 0

    if(pid == 0) { //this is the child
        for(i = 0; i < 5; i++) { //scan the first half of the array
            if(array[i] == findThisNumber) {
                printf("%d found at index %d\n", findThisNumber, i);
            }
        }
    } else { //this is the parent
        for(i = 6; i < 10; i++) { //scan the second half
            if(array[i] == findThisNumber) {
                printf("%d found at index %d\n", findThisNumber, i);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

In this example, the program splits into two processes and each process searches half of the array. I ran a the same program with 1000000000 elements in the array and these are the times:

```
time ./noFork.exe
real    0m0.796s

time ./a.exe
real    0m0.391s
```

I hope that helps, if I can clear anything else up let me know.

Answer (score 3):

I recommend you to check out posix threads. The difference is that threads work in the same process so they share address space (imo it is faster and easier to exchange data between threads then between processes). To search faster you should divide N dimensional array to X groups(smaller arrays - one for each thread/process) and pass each group of N dimensional data to particular thread(pthread)/process(fork).